# Iterate through array of objects and obtain a new array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, iteration

I have below array of objects with each object having a `projects` attribute which further has its array of objects.

```
const data = [
    {
        "title": "Release",
        "projects": [
            {
                "name": "Server",
                "result": {
                    "success": 0,
                    "failure": 100
                },
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Payments",
        "projects": [
            {
                "name": "Platform1",
                "result": {
                    "success": 100,
                    "failure": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Platform2",
                "result": {
                    "success": 50,
                    "failure": 50,
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I wanted to iterate through it and get the result as follows. `name` is nothing but concatenation of `title` and `name` from above data.

```
const result = [
    {
      name: 'Release-Server',
      success: 0,
      failure: 100,
    },
    {
      name: 'Payments-Platform1',
      success: 100,
      failure: 0,
    },
    {
      name: 'Payments-Platform2',
      success: 50,
      failure: 5,
    },
];
```

I have tried below ways but not able to figure out how to get exactly the result as shown above. can someone pls help on this.

```
data.forEach(prj => {
        prj.projects.forEach((project) => {
          // unable to get how to push these details into a new array of object
        })
      });
```

Comment: `map` and `flatMap` might be helpful here.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu i know map will allow to create a new array of object but havent used flatMap. Do you have an example i can refer to ?

Comment: it was just an idea. The "practical example" section on the following link may help: https://davidtang.io/2019-03-09-flattening-arrays-in-javascript-with-flat-and-flatMap/

Comment: [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is just a combination of [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), just like the name suggests

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following (Make sure you add checks for null/undefined references)

```js
const data = [{
    "title": "Release",
    "projects": [{
      "name": "Server",
      "result": {
        "success": 0,
        "failure": 100
      },
    }]
  },
  {
    "title": "Payments",
    "projects": [{
        "name": "Platform1",
        "result": {
          "success": 100,
          "failure": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Platform2",
        "result": {
          "success": 50,
          "failure": 50,
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

const result = data.flatMap(item =>
  item.projects.map(project => ({
    name: `${item.title}-${project.name}`,
    success: project.result.success,
    failure: project.result.failure
  })));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: As a sidenote (nothing is wrong). Instead of defining `success` and `failure` explicitly you can also just [spread out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `project.result`. This is usefull when at a later stage you want to add a property to the `result` object. This way you don't have to change the loop to also include that new property

Answer (score 2):

You should use `flatMap` first because you have will change the number of elements (you start with 2, you end with 3) and inside a simple `map` to convert 1:1 each project into your final object.

### Working Demo

```js
const data = [{
    "title": "Release",
    "projects": [{
      "name": "Server",
      "result": {
        "success": 0,
        "failure": 100
      },
    }]
  },
  {
    "title": "Payments",
    "projects": [{
        "name": "Platform1",
        "result": {
          "success": 100,
          "failure": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Platform2",
        "result": {
          "success": 50,
          "failure": 50,
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

var groupedData = data.flatMap((el) =>
  el.projects.map((proj) => ({
    name: el.title + "-" + proj.name,
    success: proj.result.success,
    failure: proj.result.failure,
  }))
);

console.log(groupedData);
```